# Skak Installation

Tags: installing, chess, skak

I want to put chess diagrams in a LaTeX file, and from what I can tell http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/chess/skak/ is the best way to do this. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to install the package. skakdoc.pdf gives you these directions:

Basically all you have to do is to follow the guidelines in the makefile. First you create all the required directories (stated in the install section of the makefile) and then you run the `make install` command.

The install section of the makefile says this:

```
install: fonts doc
    install   skak*.600pk $(DESTPK)
    install   skak*.600gf $(DESTGF)
    install   skak*.tfm   $(DESTTFM)
    install   mf/skak*.mf    $(DESTSOURCE)
    install   tex/skak.sty    $(INPUTS)
    install   tex/lambda.sty  $(INPUTS)
    install   *.ps            $(DESTDOC)
    @echo "Remember to run texhash!"
```

I have no idea how to follow these instructions. Help?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, then they are marked as a code sample. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it).

Comment: Ignore such old installation instructions. Always tries first to use the package manager of your TeXsystem. I also suggest that you look at the package chessboard and xskak.

Comment: You should explain more about your computer OS as that affects the instructions. Are you running Windows, Mac, or Linux? If Linux, which distribution? TeX Live doesn't have tlmgr if you are using Ubuntu. If Windows, using TeXnicCenter can install the packages for you on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TeX distribution probably has tools for installing packages, so you don't have to do it manually.  MikTeX has the Package Manager, which you will find in the Start menu, while TeX Live has [tlmgr](http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#install__option_____pkg___).

Comment: If you are using MikTeX, chances are that it will automatically install the package when you first compile a document with `\usepackage{skak}`. If you manually installed TeX Live, then you probably did a full install, otherwise run `tlmgr install skak` (as root or via `sudo`). If you installed TeX Live via a Linux package manager you might need to hunt for the correct package. In Debian/Ubuntu it is `texlive-games`. MacTeX probably has a package manager of its own.

Comment: I'm using TeXShop--is that an equivalent of MikTeX/TeX Live?

Comment: @pgaf TeXShop is an editor, not a TeX distribution. You can find out which distribution you are using by running `latex --version` in a command line (typically the end of the first line will state the distribution).

Comment: @Caramdir Thanks for the help! Seems to be working :)